# How do I delete rows from a data frame comparing it to another data frame and only keeping matching indices?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rand(6,6), index = 'A B C D E F'.split(), columns = 'U V W X Y Z'.split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rand(3,6), index = 'B D E'.split(), columns = 'U V W X Y Z'.split())
```

How do I delete the rows from df1 that don't match the index of those in df2? I want to be able to keep the original values in the remaining rows of df1.

Comment: What do you want to keep? Common indices between two dataframes or rows that are not in df2?

Comment: I want to keep common indices. So in this case, df1 would have the rows with indices B, D, and E when updated. Also, my original data frames are several hundred rows so I don't want to do it manually but by index matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this works as well:

```
df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_2', how='inner')[df1.columns]
```

Output:

```
    U   V   W   X   Y   Z
B   3   7   0   5   6   0
D   4   9   6   8   0   9
E   0   6   1   6   8   6
```